# Custom tag.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm very new to PHP and have some trouble wrapping my head around it sometimes so please bear with me.

I have a lot of categories and a lot of tags. I started making category-slug.php templates but it'd probably be best for me to just use category.php and tag.php templates. I just can't get them to work unless I add in something like `'category_name' => 'art'`. I've also read that querying isn't ideal (I think that's what I'm doing?), but I have had custom development done and I'm not sure if that has or hasn't been left as my only option.

```
 $page_content = "";
 if (have_posts()) : 
     while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $page_content .= get_the_content(); 
     endwhile; 
 endif;     

 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' 
 => $paged );
```

And then later on I have this with post title, date, excerpts, etc. to follow.

```
 <?php
      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
 ?>
```

How do I make the category.php and tag.php pages specific to each unique slug without having to manually make each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category Template Hierarchy, as described in WP codex:

> The Template Hierarchy specifies that WordPress will use the first Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory from the following list:
>
> 1. category-slug.php
> 2. category-ID.php
> 3. category.php
> 4. archive.php
> 5. index.php

You don't have to do any custom WP_Query to get the posts of category.

```
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_content();//this is the content of the single post, belonging to this category
        the_title();//title of the single post
        the_excerpt();//excerpt of the single post
        //and so on
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

It's the similar scenario for tags as well.

More details on [Category Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) and [Tag Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates).

Comment: I've read about the hierarchies a bunch. I took a look at what my lowest hierarchical template was in the theme itself, and it was archive.php, so I've made that now in my child theme (I hadn't cross referenced that before, so thank you!). I pulled out the query and got it to pull the right posts. Thank you!